# css accordion with radio buttons conflicts on checked

Tags: css, radio-button, accordion

I try to build an accordion with css using radio buttons, which has a css conflict on checked  button because the none checked will not collapse back to initial state. What do I wrong with my css?

here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/deroccha/pen/yGzJMM)

```css
.accordeon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item input {
  display: none;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item input:checked ~ .content {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: font-size 300ms 0ms ease-in, opacity 300ms 300ms ease-in;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item .content {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: font-size 300ms 300ms ease-in, opacity 300ms 0ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
         <div class="accordeon">

                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-1">
                            <label for="acc-1">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-2">
                            <label for="acc-2">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-3">
                            <label for="acc-3">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-4">
                            <label for="acc-4">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-5">
                            <label for="acc-5">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-6">
                            <label for="acc-6">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-7">
                            <label for="acc-7">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="" id="acc-8">
                            <label for="acc-8">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: You needed to add the same name your radio boxes example: <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="acc-1"> <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="acc-2">

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I forgot about this aspect. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just edit radio type name blank to same all name then work successfully.
Make you also this code here..

```css
.accordeon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item input {
  display: none;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item input:checked ~ .content {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: font-size 300ms 0ms ease-in, opacity 300ms 300ms ease-in;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordeon .accordeon__item .content {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: font-size 300ms 300ms ease-in, opacity 300ms 0ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
         <div class="accordeon">

                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-1">
                            <label for="acc-1">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-2">
                            <label for="acc-2">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-3">
                            <label for="acc-3">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-4">
                            <label for="acc-4">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-5">
                            <label for="acc-5">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-6">
                            <label for="acc-6">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-7">
                            <label for="acc-7">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordeon__item">
                            <input type="radio" name="ss" id="acc-8">
                            <label for="acc-8">Duis vestibulum nisl id nulla placerat?</label>
                            <div class="content">
                                Sed eu accumsan nunc. Nam placerat tristique ante nec consequat. Mauris sit amet lectus in diam vestibulum consequat ac nec elit. Donec vulputate quis ex non tincidunt. Mauris sed ipsum a ligula dapibus vestibulum. Phasellus pulvinar orci vitae pellentesque finibus. Fusce posuere pretium risus, vel sollicitudin nunc vulputate sed. Praesent pretium nisl suscipit magna vestibulum, sed ultrices est mollis.

                                Duis sit amet lacinia magna, sed semper mi. Fusce mattis commodo arcu nec ornare. Suspendisse nec purus vitae lacus tempor tincidunt a in ex. Curabitur vitae tristique erat. Sed in accumsan sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam malesuada feugiat consequat.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
              </div>
```